# Verb to use when light enters quickly into an enclosed space?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I wrote the following:

> A creaking metallic sound awakened Erin. Raising her eyes, she looked
>   to the front. It came from the door. Someone was opening the elevator.
>   She waited expectantly while the struggle continued on the other side,
>   her heart pounding with each bang. There was a screeching sound. Then,
>   finally, the door clanked open. **The bright light that (...) in blinded
>   Erin.**

I could only think of *come* and *stream*. But I think they don't give the feeling of light coming in "abruptly." I though of *rush*. But I think it's not very common to use it to describe movement of light?

What verb to use to describe light coming in rapidly?

Comment: What about *flashed*?

Comment: Aside from that, I would probably use *look at the front.* And *It came from the door* is a bit ambiguous too.

Comment: The velocity of light remains the same regardless if door is open or closed.

Comment: Light is often said to *flood in.*

Answer (score 2):

Past literature that I've read of such situations ...

> the sudden flash of light blinded her eyes
>
> the light abruptly flooded her eyes with a blinding intensity
>
> the bright light rushing in blinded her

Comment: I like *flood* in this situation. It’s very evocative—as if light were a fast-moving liquid.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *The bright light that (...) in*, try perhaps

- *The effulgent rays of light that blazed in*

And have you tried with any of these:

beamed in, zoomed in, zipped in, zapped in, barged in, rushed in, surged in, burst in, busted in, shot in, stormed in, pierced in, speared in?